# How can I place a marginnote inside a description (or other list environment)

Tags: positioning, lists, marginpar, xparse, marginnote

I have a macro (defined with the xparse package) that creates a `marginnote`. It works as I would like when prepended to normal paragraph text:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\dates{m g}{%
   \IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\marginnote{\scriptsize{#1}}}
       {\marginnote{\scriptsize{#2\\#1}}}}
```

I'd like to use it in a similar way against an `item` in a `description` environment, something like:

```
\begin{description}
    \item[Coding and data representation] \dates{June 2009}{September 2009} Some description
\end{description}
```

However the above snippet places the margin note under the label text, I would like it to appear on the far left of the page lined up with with item. I am happy to create a `NewDocumentEnvironment` with xparse if that would help me achieve this easier and I am open to better ways of achieving this sort of layout.

Here is a minimal example replicating the issues:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand\dates{m g}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\marginnote{\scriptsize{#1}}}
    {\marginnote{\scriptsize{#2\\#1}}}}
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{7pt}
\reversemarginpar

\begin{description}
    \item[Coding and data representation] \dates{June 2009}{September 2009} Some description
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I obtain the expected output when compiling your code snippet. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. This should probably *only* include [`marginnote`](http://ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) and [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse). Also include the versions of these packages by adding `\listfiles` *before* `\documentclass`, and include that in an [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/41853/edit) to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Werner's suggestion of providing a minimal working example I was able to establish that an inherited line of code:

```
% The offending line:
% \renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
```

Was to blame. I'm not sure of the purpose of the asterix, but I believe this is redefining the `raggedleftmarginnote` command to do nothing? Perhaps someone could comment to explain why it might have been there. Without it I get the output I desired.

Comment: Without `*`, you are allowed paragraphs within the `<replacement text>` of the command (re)definition. Otherwise (in the starred version), you're not.

Comment: the purpose of the asterisk is to say this command is not "long", that is, its argument cannot contain a paragraph break.  in fact, this definition does cause the command to do nothing, but that is because the expansion is just an open/close brace pair, i.e., nothing.  it also specifies no argument; if the original definition (i haven't checked) had an argument, as `\newcommand{\raggedleftmarginnote}[1]{...}` then if an argument for the command is in the input file with the modified definition, it will be set as ordinary text -- which is undoubtedly *not* what you want.